# Case-insensitive equals using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I've seen Restrictions.ilike('property', '%value%'), but would like to generate SQL like:  lower(property) = 'value'.  Any ideas?

I used:

```
Restrictions.eq("email", email).ignoreCase()
```

since Expression is deprecated.  The SimpleExpression will call toLowerCase() on the value, so it is not necessary to do it beforehand.

See:  [SimpleExpression source](http://viewvc.jboss.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/hibernate/core/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/criterion/SimpleExpression.java?view=markup)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Be careful of using ilike because it would allow someone to enter things like "test%" and match.  I use the following to do a case-insensitive equal in one app:

```
...
Criteria crit=session.createCriteria(Event.class);
crit.add(Expression.eq("rsvpCode","test1").ignoreCase());
...
```

Comment: Use Restrictions instead (see my answer below)

Answer (score 79):

Expression is now deprecated. Use Restrictions instead ...

```
crit(Restrictions.eq("firstName", firstName).ignoreCase());
```

Comment: This doesn't works if property is enum type. internally hibernate applies lower() to columns which actually fails for enum types. Do you know solution for this?

Comment: If you're using a mysql database, the ignorecase uses lower in the actual sql run against the database.  As you cannot create "lower" indexes in mysql(although you can in some other databases I believe).  This means that it not take advantage of any index you have on the column (in this case "firstName")

Comment: There is also a problem comparing characters as they are not strings but you would expect that ignoreCase would work with this.

Answer (score 14):

As Andy's answer suggests, this for case-insensitive searches but it is also works through to Hibernate version **4.1**:

```
crit(Restrictions.eq("firstName", firstName).ignoreCase());
```

**Versions 4.1.1 and later** of Hibernate do not support the `ignoreCase()` method on `Restriction.eq()`. For that, we have to use `ilike` with `MatchMode`.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ENTITY.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike('PROPERTY NAME', 'VALUE', MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

As an example, for a **USER** entity with **id, name, surname** properties, a case-insensitive search based on name will be:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(USER.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike('name', 'Satyam', MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

This will return all results, case insensitive.

Comment: any reason for why they dont support it anymore?

Comment: if you need to search using case-insensitive, then there is another method  `IsInsensitiveLike`... how you can do it on C# - `Restrictions.On<Entity>(c => c.Field).IsInsensitiveLike(searchText, MatchMode.Anywhere)`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not absolutely sure, but when you use Restriction.eq you obtain a SimpleExpression object, and that object suppports an ignoreCase() operation which I've never tried using but sounds like it could make a difference.

Kudos to Hibernate for not documenting what this method actually does.

Comment: Careful Uri, Gavin King or Christian Baer might be watching...  8)  They tend to be a little defensive about criticism on the Hibernate forums.

Comment: I've doing my Ph.D. research on the usability and correctness of JavaDocs... So completely omitting the JavaDocs on that methods takes away from my work ;)

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is `lower(property) = 'value'` than best way is to use Restrictions.eq with ignoreCase() instead of using ilike cuz here the exact value is know. ilike is beneficial to search a pattern or when we are not aware of the exact value.
Only problem with ignoreCase() is, it will not restrict your results to lower case and also include results with other cases
, but i think is is the only available option hibernate offers.

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClassName.class);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("PROPERTY", propertyName).ignoreCase()).uniqueResult();
```

Now if I understand your question correctly, your db has these values:
ABC, abc, aBC, aBc...and so on, you want to convert them to lower case and then compare with some value say "ABC" or "abc". YOu can do this by further processing the list you got.

You can save this result in a list.

```
List<ClassName> listOfAllMatches =  criteria.list(); // gives all matched results (ABC, abc, aBC, aBc)



List<ClassName> finalResult = listOfAllMatches.stream().map(x -> x.getPropertyName().toLowerCase()).filter(y ->y.getPropertyName()== value).collect(Collectors.toList());

//convert this field to lower case using map() and filter your results with filter() function.
```

YOU can further add this list to Criteria and process it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Criterion.ilike. For more information check this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode)).

Answer (score -1):

`crit(Restrictions.eq("firstName", firstName).ignoreCase());` works.

This did returns a `SimpleExpression Object` but It generates `lower(firstname)` query. So this works.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation