# how to check username and password in hibernate criteria with case sensitive

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple login page username is "Admin" and password is "hello" but criteria function accepts all values like "HELlo" "HELLO" this types. I want to only accept case sensitive result. what can i do any one please help me.

```
public Members logIn(Members members) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory
        .getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Members.class);
    criteria.add(Expression.eq("memberUserName", members.getMemberUserName()));
    criteria.add(Expression.eq("password", members.getPassword()));

    Members Member=(Members) criteria.uniqueResult();
    return Member;
}
```

model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Members")
public class Members{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "memberId")
    private int memberId;

    @Column(name="memberUserName", unique=true)
    private String memberUserName;

    @Column(name="passwrd")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="memberName")
    private String memberName;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case-insensitive equals using Hibernate Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624604/case-insensitive-equals-using-hibernate-criteria) (check the more recent answers, the accepted one is deprecated now)

Comment: Seems he wants to be case sensitive when your link is case insensitive. Suprised Hibernate would be case insensitive by default though ?

Comment: @TheBakker Indeed, but same surprise to be honnest ^^ I should check that, I don't remember it to be case insensitve... This could be depending on the DB used actually (well the encoding)

Comment: Maybe the column definition in the database is case insensitive?

Comment: How to check db. it is case insensitive?

Comment: What database are you using @Manihtraa?

Comment: MYSQL workbench 6.3 @Naros

Answer (score 0):

MySQL by default uses case insensitive collations.  You either need set the database collation so that it's entirely case sensitive or you need to apply a custom column definition that specifies a column specific collation for case sensitivity.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448861/1572269).

Comment: how can i do this in hibernate criteria?

Comment: You cannot do this as part of the Criteria API.  This is something you have to do either as part of the `@Column(columnDefinition="...")` configuration or you need to manipulate the table column manually.